# Why is the command re.sub('[^0-9]', '', '59kg') removing 'kg' from '59kg'?

Tags: python-3.x

Why is the command

> re.sub('[^0-9]', '', '59kg')

removing 'kg' from '59kg'.
The output is

> '59'

From what I found online , ^ means in the beginning of the word. So the command should remove any numeric characters in the beginning of the word '59kg'. Why is it removing 'kg'?

Comment: You can test your regex patterns on [regex 101](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If inside the squared parentheses, the ^ character indicates a negation.

`[^0-9]` therefore means "every character except numbers between 0 and 9" and causes the input string "59kg" to become "59" after the `re.sub` function execution.

See documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp (`Character Sets` section)